# Javascript Object Default Value

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create library for displaying graph using highcharts. For this i am trying to use object for each module to be used. I am trying to make basic object, which have default values. I would like to create new instance from basic object and assign values to them. so it will be easy for others to understand and implement.

```
var graph_main = function(){};
graph_main.graph_title = "graph title";

var gm_1 = new graph_main();
gm_1.graph_title = " done ";
var gm_2 = new graph_main();
console.log(" cool " + gm_1.graph_title + " itt "+ gm_2.graph_title);
```

"gm_2" is not printing the "graph title" as its default value. it is showing undefeined.

Answer (score 0):

Write graph_main like :

```
var graph_main = function(){
   this.graph_title = "graph title";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `.prototype` in

```
graph_main.prototype.graph_title = "graph title";
```

that is necessary for the default values that new instances inherit.

---

However I'd recommend not to use constructors at all here. Just go for pain prototype inheritance directly:

```
var graph_main = {
    graph_title: "graph title"
};

var gm_1 = Object.create(graph_main);
gm_1.graph_title = " done ";
var gm_2 = Object.create(graph_main);
console.log(" cool " + gm_1.graph_title + " itt "+ gm_2.graph_title);
```